# Change Windows Locale / Culture without using code

Tags: windows, locale, culture

This ought to be simple and it probably is but I can't seem to find an answer to this question...

I am developing C# application using Visual Studio 2008 and the application supports a number of different languages. To test different languages on the development machine is simple (e.g. temporarily adding `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("sv")` to the application will let me test the Swedish translation) but how can I change the Locale / Culture on a test machine without using code? I want to use the following steps for my tests :

1. Install Windows on test machine (English version).
2. Install application on test machine.
3. Run tests using English.
4. Change Locale / Culture on test machine to Swedish.
5. Repeat tests using Swedish.
6. Repeat for every language the market division might think of;)

Answer (score 3):

From the start menu, run intl.cpl. .NET initialized from [GetUserDefaultUILanguage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318137%28VS.85%29.aspx), which returns something different than the installation language only if you have MUI packs installed, see Microsoft's [overview article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374098%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: But that doesn't work as expected. Maybe there is some code I am missing in the application itself. The symptom I have is that the application uses the language of the Windows installation and not the current regional settings.